# How to install GSSAPI Python module?

Tags: python, installation, ldap, python-2.6, gssapi

I am trying to install the GSSAPI module through pip but I receive this error that I don't know how to resolve.

> Could not find main GSSAPI shared library. Please try setting
> GSSAPI_MAIN_LIB yourself or setting ENABLE_SUPPORT_DETECTION to
> 'false'

I need this to work on Python 2.6 for LDAP3 authentication.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Summary, for the impatient**

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/krb5-config.mit /usr/bin/krb5-config
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip libkrb5-dev
$ sudo pip install gssapi
```

---

**And now the details...**

I have a Debian system that uses Heimdal Kerberos. I'll take you through what I had to do to get it working for me. Hopefully, this can help someone else as well.

---

### Problem 1 - krb5-config: command not found

`setup.py` for gssapi uses the `krb5-config` command to find the GSSAPI library to link against (see [here](https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi/blob/c66f7c12052ed0daeddd4a2cee01fc9ba94df785/setup.py#L56)). Because my system was installed using Heimdal instead of MIT Kerberos, the executable command has been renamed to `krb5-config.mit` so `setup.py` misses it.

```
$ krb5-config --libs gssapi  # doesn't work
bash: krb5-config: command not found
```

I created a symlink to get it to work for the install:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/krb5-config.mit /usr/bin/krb5-config
$ krb5-config --libs gssapi  # does work
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,-z,relro -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err
```

---

### Problem 2 - libgssapi_krb5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

`setup.py` is looking in `/usr/lib` for the gssapi library to link against. In Debian Jesse, most libs are now kept in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Again, a symlink can fix this:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so
```

---

### Problem 3 - error: unknown type name ‘gss_key_value_set_desc’

The build fails because it does not recognize a symbol in the library. The reason for this is that it was not able to get the right header file. Silly me, I forgot to include the `-dev` package for krb5 headers. Fix this with apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

---

### Finally - Install gssapi

Now we should be all ready to go.

```
$ sudo pip install gssapi
```

If you want to tidy up, you can remove the symlink to the `krb5-config.mit` command:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/krb5-config
```

Comment: Also, to install `pip` on a Debian box, issue `sudo apt-get install python-pip` then `sudo pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: downvoted because the symlinking of system files is not needed at all, the libkrb5-dev package will install these files, see my answer,

Comment: What about on windows environments ?

Comment: in my case, I needed to symlink to `/usr/lib/mit/bin/krb5-config`

Answer (score 22):

`sudo apt install libkrb5-dev`
actually installs /usr/bin/krb5-config and /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so

so none of the symlinking was needed, just install libkrb5-dev and you should be good.

Comment: The package was probably fixed since I had to do this many years ago. Often-times doing manual symlinking is necessary evil but only lasts temporarily until upstream package maintainers are aware of the issue and fix it properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue got resolved after installing the package "krb5-libs" in Centos.
Basically we need to have libgssapi_krb5.so file for installing gssapi.

Comment: You should also need `krb5-devel`.